# How to Display Dynamic Menu in WPF application

Tags: wpf, menu

I am new to WPF. I try to create a dynamic menus in WPF. I plan to use data from a database. I am using WPF Application in vs 2010.

Until now what I done was:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="725" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" >
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ThemeMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActivateCommand}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsActive}" />
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <MenuItem Header="Themes" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ThemeMenuItemStyle}"  />
    </Menu>
</Window>
```

But I am stuck in code behind to how assign the value to menu.

I need the full page code to achieve this. I plan to use list as datasource.

Comment: how your data look like ? what do you mean stucked in code behind ? you should have a list call Themes with the properties in the style binding

Comment: My data look like... Parent 1,Child 1 ,Child 2,(childs have parent id as reference). Stucked means i have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me (simple example for "dynamic" menu)

view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyData2">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ThemeMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding More}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <MenuItem Header="Themes" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ThemeMenuItemStyle}"  />
    </Menu>


</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyThemesViewModel();
    }

    public class MyThemesViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyData> _themes = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
        public ObservableCollection<MyData> Themes
        {
            get { return _themes; }
            set { _themes = value; }
        }

        public MyThemesViewModel()
        {
            Themes.Add(new MyData("a"));
            Themes.Add(new MyData("b"));
            Themes.Add(new MyData("c"));
            Themes.Add(new MyData("d"));
        }
    }



}
public class MyData
{ 
    ObservableCollection<MyData2> _more = new ObservableCollection<MyData2>(){new MyData2("h")};
    public ObservableCollection<MyData2> More {get { return _more; } }

    public MyData(string name)
    {

        Name = name;
    }
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

}
public class MyData2
{

    public MyData2(string name)
    {

        Name = name;
    }
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: But how do i add or Show sub menu..For Eg. Themes under it A & B. Then under A >>1,2,3 the sub menus will come.

Comment: I've added some code for sub menu, you should start with this but notice what you'r doing this is just an example

Comment: use DataTemplate that's the main idea

Comment: Ya.. i use data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MenuService
{
    private List<MenuItem> allMenuItems;

    public MenuService()
    {
        allMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    public List<MenuItem> GetParentMenuItems()
    {
        List<MenuItem> parentItems = allMenuItems.FindAll(x => x.Parent == null);

        return parentItems;
    }

    public void AddMenuItem(MenuItem item, string parentName = "")
    {
        if (parentName == string.Empty)
        {
            this.allMenuItems.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            MenuItem parent = allMenuItems.Find(x => x.Name == parentName);
            if (parent != null)
            {
                item.Parent = parent;
                parent.AddSubMenu(item);
            }
            allMenuItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem item in allMenuItems)
        {
            item.RemoveSubMenu(menuItem);                
        }

        if (this.allMenuItems.Contains(menuItem))
        {
            this.allMenuItems.Remove(menuItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Jeff Jones
Lead at [Mobile Application Development Company](http://www.zibrasoft.com/services/mobile-development)

Comment: Nice.. But how do i assign it to the menu in design page?